# Nick Szabo's bitgold announcement email in 1998

Tags: history

I am looking for Nick Szabo's bit gold announcement email in 1998 and discussions of it. How can I find them? Which mailing list they were posted? Any archived version?

PS. I am not talking about his blog post in 2005.

Comment: AFAIK it was not a public mailing list so you are looking for a private communication

Answer (score 1):

> **Which mailing list they were posted?**

According to [Aaron Van Wirdum in a 2018 article in Bitcoin Magazine](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/culture/genesis-files-bit-gold-szabo-was-inches-away-inventing-bitcoin) the 1998 proposal was a private communication.

> Szabo first came up with Bit Gold in 1998, though **he only fully described it in public in 2005**.

...

> By 2008 — 10 years after first proposing it **in private** — Szabo brought up Bit Gold on his blog once again

(my emphasis)

This would explain why it is not in any public record from 1998. It wasn't distributed to any public mailing list.